# File copy utility or file manager with each byte report while copying?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, file-transfer

Please suggest copy utility or file manager program, which reports each byte copied.

I have a problems while copying. Copying process hangs, and I want to see how it happens, so I want to see how many bytes are copied for each file copying, like it is done while downloading file from internet.

**UPDATE**

Sorry guys the question is about Windows.

Answer (score 2):

you rather have given the answer to your question yourself. You say "like it is done while downloading file from internet". So why not simulate 'downloading'?

setup an wildcard rsync configuration:

```
/tmp/rsyncd.conf:

uid = root
gid = root
use chroot = no
read only = no

[root]
   path = /
```

start a temporary rsync server (with root privileges):

```
rsync --daemon --config=/tmp/rsyncd.conf --no-detach
```

enjoy copying in another terminal with progress meter, byte counting and everything you like (following standard rsync syntax). In the example below you can limit the copy bandwidth in effect even all copying takes place within your local machine only. This may ease your copy problems by the way:

```
rsync -va --progress --bwlimit=80 localhost::root/<src> <dst>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipemeter (available in all good Linux distros) will do what you want.

It just redirects stdin to stdout, but measures the data going through it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use tar like this:

```
tar -C <src-directory> -cf - . | tar -C <dst-directory> -xvvf -
```

depending on your needs you add 'vv' either on the sending or the receiving side. Though this still does not report *every single* byte transmitted :-)